# How to use str_replace in Smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm using PHP smarty to declare a link :

```
<{foreach item=list key=num from=$product}> 
    <li><a href="<{$config.weburl}>/<{$list.somename}>"><{$list.somename}></a></li>
<{/foreach}>`
```

and the resulting link when mouseover is :

```
"http:/domain/some name"
```

I need to str_replace the space char (some name) with an underscore (some_name), how to do that?? like result below :

```
"http:/domain/some_name"
```

I'm using the following code but it does not work. How to use str_replace with an array in html?

```
<a href="<{$config.weburl}>/'.str_replace(array(' ','%'),array('_','-'),<{$list.somename}>).'">
```

Comment: Are you really using `<{` and `}>` as your Smarty delimiters?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use PHP functions as Smarty modifiers, but Smarty has [a built-in `replace` modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl). Use it like this:

```
<{foreach item=list key=num from=$product}> 
    <li><a href="<{$config.weburl}>/<{$list.somename|replace:' ':'_'}>"><{$list.somename}></a></li>
<{/foreach}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
str_replace(" ", "_", $config.weburl)
```

**This means** : replace the character " " (space) by "_" in $config.weburl.

This would replace all spaces with underscores in PHP. Try `{ str_replace(" ", "_", $config.weburl) }` to echo it with Smarty PHP, but as I don't use it, I'm not sure this will work.

Here's some docs : http://php.net//manual/fr/function.str-replace.php